# What is the different between url() and getUrl()

Tags: url

What is the different between url() and getUrl()

Ex:

```
   {% set solutionIcon = solution.solutionIcon.one() ?? null %}
   <div class="img-wrapper mt--3 mb-2 mx-auto">
      {% if solutionIcon %}
         <img src="{{ solutionIcon.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ solutionIcon.title }}">
      {% endif %}
   </div>

   {% set solutionIcon = solution.solutionIcon.one() ?? null %}
   <div class="img-wrapper mt--3 mb-2 mx-auto">
      {% if solutionIcon %}
         <img src="{{ solutionIcon.url() }}" alt="{{ solutionIcon.title }}">
      {% endif %}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They do the same thing. `url()` is an alias of `getUrl()`. This is the link from the Craft 2 docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/templating/entrymodel.html#url.

It works the same way in Craft 3, but I can never find anything in the Craft 3 docs.